# View references held before onPause are valid after onResume?

Tags: android

In an android activity If I cache the View references taken from an activity layout before onPause() is called, are they guaranteed to be valid if I use them after onResume() call ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Comment: Yup. Check out the android activity lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Check out the android activity lifecycle.
[Activity Pausing](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html)

[Activity Stopping](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html)